# Show that p plus signs and q minus signs may be placed in a row so that no two minus signs are together in p + 1 choose q ways.

Tags: combinatorics

I know the standard way to solve this one, which is first placing p plus signs in a row and then choose q places from p+1 possible places to place the minus sign. However, I am curious about the other possible way to solve it --- that is, we first place all the minus signs in a row. To make sure no two minus signs are adjacent to each other, we then place (p-1) plus signs between them (i.e., insert one plus sign between each two adjacent minus signs). As a result, we have (p-q+1) plus signs left to freely place them anywhere in the possible 2p slots. However, I have no clue how to do it from here. I am not sure if we can solve this problem in this way; if we can, can you please give some hints or help to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part to have a solution, a necessary condition is that $p+1 >= q$,

so let us say, for example, that $p = 8, q=5$

Consider the $q's$ placed in a line and  $4 p's$ placed in the $4$ "bins" the $q's\,$ form. $\,4\, p's$ are left over to place

The spaces left and right of all the  $q's$ can be considered as $2$ extra bins to contain the balance $4 p's$

PLacing the $p's$ one by one, considering them as distinct, we can put them in $6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9$ ways, but as they are identical, the answer comes to

$$\frac{6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9}{4!} \equiv \binom95$$

You should be able to put it back in the generalised $p,q$ form

Comment: The answer seems not correct. Take your example; the correct answer should be (8+1) choose 5 which = 9!/(5!*4!) = 126 ways, not 8 - 5 + 2 = 5 ways

Comment: @Rui: I thought you wanted just one $p$ between two $q's$. I will shortly review the answer

Comment: @Rui: Done, and equivalence to your first method established